# How to escape mask rules in kendo maskedtextbox for angular2?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-maskedtextbox

I need to build a mask where some charachters are fixed, like a number where the user have to specify last three digits.

How can I escape the "0" default mask behaviour?

the docs says to use backslash character, but I can't figure out how it should works.

example: my mask needs to show the number 12000___ and user have to enter last 3 digits

html:

```
<kendo-maskedtextbox [mask]="mask"></kendo-maskedtextbox>
```

ts:

```
mask = "12\0\0\0000";
```

but it doesn't compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backslash is a escape character in (JavaScript) strings, thus you need to escape the backslash.

Like this: `mask = "12\\0\\0\\0000"`

I've also prepared a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ijBqny1cf9M02U0AmRIo?p=preview).